# From Uniform distribution to Normal distribution

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a normal distribution, but instead of specifying the `n = 100` in `mvrnorm`, I want to use the data generated in the normal distribution

```
mu1=c(0,1) 
Sigma= matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1),ncol=2) 
set.seed(1234)
X1_u=runif(100)
set.seed(1234)
X1_distribution=mvrnorm(X1_u,mu=mu1,Sigma=Sigma)
```

The error I have in this line

```
X1_distribution=mvrnorm(X1_u,mu=mu1,Sigma=Sigma)
```

Comment: The first argument of `mvrnorm` is _the number of samples_. This should be an integer, but you provided a vector of uniformly distributed variables (100 of them), which looks like `[1] 0.113703411 0.622299405 0.609274733 [...]`. So let me ask you: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to use the data from the uniform distribution in the normal distribution

Comment: This doesn't make any sense for me. What do you mean by _I try to use the data from the uniform distribution in the normal distribution_?

Comment: I was thinking of using generate non-Gaussian data. But I think if I use `mvrnorm` they will always be within a normal distribution

Comment: `mvrnorm` simulates a Multivariate Normal Distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the inverse CDF method to generate the independent normal random variables then use eigen decomposition to generate the desired Multinormal distribution:

```
mu1 <- c(0,1) 
Sigma <- matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1),ncol=2) 
n <- 10000 # Number of values to be generated

Z <- replicate(length(mu1), qnorm(runif(n)))
# Z is the independent normal random variables:

E <- eigen(Sigma)
L <- E[[2]] %*% diag(sqrt(E[[1]])) %*%t(E[[2]])
X <- t(t(Z %*% L) + mu1) # The desired result:

colMeans(X)
[1] 0.0008338121 0.9921517224

cov(X)
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 1.0070731 0.5128771
[2,] 0.5128771 1.0202561

plot(X[,1]);
plot(X[,2])

plot(density(X))
plot(X)
```

[image]

[image]